# Horizontal dropdown navigation pure css

Tags: css, navigation, hover, onhover, navigation-style

I am working on a site with a horizontal dropdown navigation but it's not working as it should.

I can't get the second level navigation to hide until the first is hovered on. I get that I need the direct descendant. Also when the current page is on the nav needs to show but I just cannot work it out!

The css I have in there at the moment is below. I can't tell you how much I would appreciate any help.

The site is: http://www.lifetimetraining.co.uk/

```
#navSection{
background:#fff url(../images/topNavBg.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
clear:both;
color:#fff;
height:87px;
position:relative;
width:1000px
```

}

```
#navSection a{
color:#fff
```

}

```
#primaryNav li{
border-right:1px solid #6a8db3;
float:left;
font-size:.83em;
font-weight:bold;
height:56px;
line-height:1.1em;
width:169px
```

}

```
#primaryNav li a{
display:block;
height:36px;
padding:10px 0 10px 20px;
text-decoration:none;
width:150px
```

}

```
#primaryNav li strong{
display:block;
font-size:1.5em;
line-height:1.06em
```

}

```
#primaryNav li ul.secondLevel{
clear:both;
border-radius:0 0 14px 14px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 14px 14px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 14px 14px;
height:31px;
left:-99999px;
line-height:31px;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
top:56px;
width:1000px
```

}

```
#primaryNav li ul.secondLevel li{
position:relative;
width:auto
```

}

```
#primaryNav li li.first a{
border-radius:0 0 0 14px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 0 14px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 0 14px;
padding-left:20px
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.current ul{
left:0;
z-index:3
```

}

```
#primaryNav ul li{
border:none;
font-size:1.2em;
height:31px;
width:auto
```

}

```
#primaryNav li ul a{
display:block;
float:left;
font-size:.9em;
font-weight:bold;
height:31px;
line-height:31px;
padding:0 10px;
text-decoration:none;
width:auto
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.firstLevel.current>a,#primaryNav li.firstLevel:hover>a{
background:#00a3a8 url('../images/colour3Gradient.png') repeat-x scroll 0 0
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.current ul,#primaryNav li.current ul li a{
background-color:#00a3a8
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.current li:hover a,#primaryNav li.current li.current a{
background-color:#00b7bc
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel,
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel li,
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel li a{
border-radius:none
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel{
min-width:210px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:31px;
left:0;
visibility:hidden;
background-color:#51c5c3;
border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel li{
font-size:1em;
display:block;
width:auto;
float:left;
clear:left;
height:auto
```

}

```
#primaryNav li.firstLevel ul li ul.thirdLevel li a{
background:none;
height:auto;
display:block;
padding:6px 0 6px 20px;
line-height:16px
```

}

Comment: any plan to use HTML 5 elements ? if yes , try `<nav>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample of how simplest menu work, if you could implement all you code on jsfiddle alongside with js i could find what gone wrong, bcs i dont see where you set visibility on child
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYSyY/1/)

```
.
```